# Подсветка иконки очереди проверок

Tags: поддержка, очередь-проверок, навигация

В каких ситуациях иконка очереди проверок подсвечивается цветом <s>детской неожиданности</s>?

> [image: иконка очередь]

Задал аналогичный вопрос на MSE: [Algorithm for review icon highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296736/339911)

Comment: судя по всему, это индикатор новых сообщений в очереди проверки. загорается бледно-оранжевым, если с момента последнего посещения появились новые жертвы

Comment: @PashaPash может быть. Но если так, то ещё и с каким-то кэшем или тайм-аутом. Было например 222 на закрытие, и 2 низкокачественных. Горело огнём. Сейчас смотрю 219 и 4 - не горит. Может просто сумма всех очередей проверяется на рост?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ответ нашелся](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/346653/3240681) на страницах MSO.

Иконка подсвечивается если:

1. Не кликали кнопку очередей проверки в верхней панели, не проводили проверку любых сообщений и не посещали страницу проверки `/review` в течение некоторого времени (сейчас это 1 час) и ...
2. ... кол-во задач, требующих проверки более некоторого числа (на enSO это 513, но данное число может быть изменено без дополнительного уведомления). На ruSO - 30.

Comment: Эм.. Не похоже...

Comment: @Qwertiy мопед не мой.

Comment: А я думал, оно подсвечиватеся, когда что-то появляется в очереди проверок правок.